# Lemma 2.2.3. For any natural numbers $n$ and $m$, $n + ( m{+\!+})$ = $(n+m){+\!+}$: Analysis 1, Terence Tao

Tags: real-analysis, induction

I'm self-learning real analysis using Terence Tao Analysis books. The book is very lucid. But in some cases Terence quickly go through the proof. And it becomes difficult for lesser mortals like us to understand. Lemma 2.2.3 is one of them. So, I'm requesting you guyz if you can help me understand this proof. The proof is the following:

> [image]

The portion, I'm not getting is:

> But by definition of addition, $0 + (m{+\!+}) = m{+\!+}$ and $0 + m = m$, so both sides are equal to $m{+\!+}$ and are thus equal to each other.

Why $m{+\!+}$ & $m$ are equal. Similay, he is using similar logic in following section:

> Similarly, we have $(n{+\!+} )+m = (n+m){+\!+}$ by the definition of addition, and so the right-hand side is also equal to $((n+m){+\!+}){+\!+}.$

These might be very simple logic. But I'm having hard time getting grasp of it. If someone can explain it, I'll be extremely grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tao never asserts that $m$ and $m{+\!+}$ are equal. What he asserts is that $0+(m{+\!+})=m{+\!+}$ and that $(0+m){+\!+}=m{+\!+}$. So, in particular, since both $0+(m{+\!+})$ and $(0+m){+\!+}$ are equal to $m{+\!+}$, $0+(m{+\!+})=(0+m){+\!+}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This clears the doubt. But in the line "But by definition of addition, 0 + (m++) = m++ and 0 + m = m", why he added "0+m = m". We know by definition 0 + (m++) = m++. What's the reason for adding additional equation? Your answer completely explained what I asked. But just wanted to be thorough in my understanding. Thanks again!

Comment: He needed to know that $0+m=m$ in order to deduce that $(0+m)++=m++$.

Comment: For reasons of spacing, please use `m{+}+` instead of `m++` in MathJax.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos: Perfect!! Thanks for your answer! Each step matter in maths :)

Comment: @Christoph: Sure...will do this from the next time.

Comment: @Christoph Nice suggestion!